# Values not being passed to on submit function in redux-form 6.0.5

Tags: javascript, redux-form

For some reason, when I use anonymous functions to define my components, the values never get passed to the submit handler.  I am using redux-form 6.0.5

I created the following simple form:

```
class TestForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    submit(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    renderField(field) {
        return (
            <input {...field.input} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={field.placeholder} />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <Field name="title"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        component={this.renderField} />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Category</label>
                    <Field name="category"
                        placeholder="Category"
                        component={category => (
                         <input type="text" className="form-control" {...category}/>
                        )
                        } />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

When submit(e) is called, the console displays the value for the title field, but not value for category displayed.

Is there something wrong with my anonymous function for the category field, or are anonymous functions not supported as the component?

Answer (score 1):

I am actually in the same course as you and wanted to post about what the issue is. There is a breaking change from V4 to V6 and in the course we are using V4 of redux-form. I like to learn on the most up to date so I updated everything but it's a pain but I did find the solution to having the form actually save. First things first you have to have `{ connect }` still used separately from `{ reduxForm }`. Furthermore there are no more fields now there is Field so `{ reduxForm, Field }` this is for V6. as for the working code that needs to be seen .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';

const renderInput = field => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>{field.label}</label>
    <input className="form-control" {...field.input} type=  {field.type}/>
  </div>
);

const renderTextarea = field => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>{field.label}</label>
    <textarea className="form-control" {...field.input}/>
  </div>
);


class PostsNew extends Component{
  render(){
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.createPost)}>
        <h3>Create A New Post</h3>

        <Field
          label="Title"
          name="title"
          type="text"
          component={renderInput} />

        <Field
          label="Categories"
          name="categories"
          type="text"
          component={renderInput}
        />

        <Field
          label="Content"
          name="content"
          component={renderTextarea}
        />

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'PostsNewForm', 
})(connect(null,{ createPost })(PostsNew));
```

I hope this helps some how if not to your exact question there is a migration guide. [v5-v6](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/MigrationGuide.md/)